Yum command failing with missing directory error on AWS EC2 instance
I am encountering an error message indicating that the required directory is missing when I try to run yum update or yum install commands on my AWS EC2 instance. I am not sure why this error is occurring. Could you please help me understand the cause of this error and provide a solution?
[ec2-user@ip-000-000-000-000 ~]$ sudo yum update

yum: can't open file '/home/ec2-user/update': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

[ec2-user@ip-000-000-000-000 ~]$ sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

yum: can't open file '/home/ec2-user/install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have attempted to use dnf or microdnf as alternatives, but they also require installation via yum, which is not possible due to the initial error I am facing.

try with absolute path of yum and see if it works.
sudo /usr/bin/yum update
sudo /usr/bin/yum install -y mongodb-org


sudo /usr/bin/yum update
sudo: /usr/bin/yum: command not found
sudo /usr/local/bin/yum update
/usr/local/bin/yum: can't open file '/home/ec2-user/update': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
